# BottomSheetDialog on non activity class

Tags: android, class, dialog

I have an app. I want it to show bottom sheet dialog. But It crashes (the exception info on the app's toast on the pic below please see it). i want the BottomSheet dialog to be in a non-activity class like the code below

Utils.java

```
package com.my.newproject5;


import android.app.*;

import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.text.style.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.animation.*;
import android.view.animation.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.*;
import org.json.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.material.*;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog;

public class Utils {
    
    
    
    public static void showBottomSheetDialog(String _title, String _message, String _btn1msg, String _btn2msg, double _icID, boolean _cancelable, double _execID, final Context _ctx) {
        final Context ctx = _ctx;
        try{
        final BottomSheetDialog bs_layout = new BottomSheetDialog(_ctx, R.style.BottomSheetLayoutTheme);
        
        bs_layout.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_error);
        
        Button btn1 = (Button)
        bs_layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        
        ImageView imageview1 = (ImageView)
        bs_layout.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        
        bs_layout.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet).setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        bs_layout.setCancelable(_cancelable);
        bs_layout.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL); 
        bs_layout.show();
        
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(ctx, "HAHAHA");
            }
        });
          
        
        }catch (Exception _e){ 
            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(ctx, _e.toString());
            }
        
     }
}
```

What did i do wrong? What i wanna achieve is to use the same BottomSheet Dialog class for all of my activity and just call
Utils.showBottomSheet(string, string,context .. etc);

Can someone help me how to make it work? And just import that class and then call it to show bottom sheet dialog? Thanks.

Error of the pic:

[I don't know how to embed the photo please click here for the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poxcr.png)

Edit: the class where i call the Utils.java class

```
package com.my.newproject5;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.annotation.*;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.text.style.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.animation.*;
import android.view.animation.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.*;
import org.json.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.material.*;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private Toolbar _toolbar;
    private AppBarLayout _app_bar;
    private CoordinatorLayout _coordinator;
    private String private_dir = "";
    
    private Button button1;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialize(_savedInstanceState);
        initializeLogic();
    }
    
    private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        _app_bar = findViewById(R.id._app_bar);
        _coordinator = findViewById(R.id._coordinator);
        _toolbar = findViewById(R.id._toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        _toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                Utils.showBottomSheetDialog("bleh", "waw", "ok", "ikr", 0, true, 9, getApplicationContext());
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "".substring((int)(0), (int)(0)));
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void initializeLogic() {
    }
    
    
    @Deprecated
    public void showMessage(String _s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationX(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[0];
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationY(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[1];
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getRandom(int _min, int _max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(_max - _min + 1) + _min;
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public ArrayList<Double> getCheckedItemPositionsToArray(ListView _list) {
        ArrayList<Double> _result = new ArrayList<Double>();
        SparseBooleanArray _arr = _list.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int _iIdx = 0; _iIdx < _arr.size(); _iIdx++) {
            if (_arr.valueAt(_iIdx))
            _result.add((double)_arr.keyAt(_iIdx));
        }
        return _result;
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public float getDip(int _input) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, _input, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayWidthPixels() {
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayHeightPixels() {
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code in Android studio it is working fine. Where you are calling this method may be your context is null. Please post the code where you are calling this method

Comment: I edited the post sir. it's there. Thanks. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Yes I got the issue
Please call like this

  Utils.showBottomSheetDialog("bleh", "waw", "ok", "ikr", 0, true, 9, MainActivity.this);

It will work